Creating Micro-frontend application in nextjs using webpack
I am using nextjs@14 version.
here is my next.config.mjs
export default (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  //console.log('defaultConfig =>', defaultConfig);
  /**
   * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
   */
  const nextConfig = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    webpack(config, { isServer }) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'remoteApp',
          filename: 'static/remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './Button': './pages/components/Button',
            // Add more components as needed
          },
          shared: {
            react: { singleton: true, eager: true },
            'react-dom': { singleton: true, eager: true },
          }
        })
      )
      return config;
    }
  }

  return nextConfig
}

I am facing below error


shell-app3@0.1.0 dev
next dev

▲ Next.js 14.2.16

Local:        http://localhost:3000

✓ Starting...
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
at ModuleFederationPlugin.getCompilationHooks (D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\webpack\lib\container\ModuleFederationPlugin.js:58:10)
at D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\webpack\lib\container\HoistContainerReferencesPlugin.js:36:33
at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:28636), :35:1)
at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:25906)
at Compiler.newCompilation (D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:147853)
at D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:148673
at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:28858), :6:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:26012)
at Compiler.compile (D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:148599)
at D:\development\shell-app3\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:491794

I have the same error when trying to integrate the latest webpack 5.96.1 into a vue.js app. I avoid this error by downgrade to 5.95.0

which webpack are you using?
